# useDispatch and connect from react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

It seems that I can use useDispatch or connect from react redux to dispatch an action or it seems that they are both the same. My question is can I just solely rely on useDispatch to pass store data for the entire react app? If not, in what situation that I must use connect? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the useDispatch hook for all your functional react components. If you have a class based component structure you won't be able to use hooks (useDispatch() and useSelector()) and therefore you'll need to use connect.

Comment: but with connect() besides dispatch actions you can pass to props some state, while the hook useDispatch is for only dispatch actions, so how can I use those redux states without `connect()`?

Comment: @pmiranda I think what you're looking for is useSelector()